# Visualizing graph using igraph package in r

Tags: r, layout, visualization, igraph

I have the correlation coefficients matrix as bellow and am trying to visualize this using `igraph` package and its `layouts`. None of the layouts output a clear network. Can anyone suggest how I can fix this?

```
dput(adjm)
structure(c(1, 0.963441407633081, 0.986207962169263, 0.979240565034286, 
0.260477742974566, 0.928971036770817, 0.990859133037916, 0.98615828324931, 
0.923912532530861, -0.328655580485871, 0.963441407633081, 1, 
0.977343669695317, 0.973832136657044, 0.251853284084679, 0.941236887557877, 
0.970317460375686, 0.979203650433608, 0.931475199702801, -0.262254189238524, 
0.986207962169263, 0.977343669695317, 1, 0.978059833099735, 0.241345600979638, 
0.934105190260024, 0.991280098453041, 0.987744430218514, 0.923127024136395, 
-0.287964556946545, 0.979240565034286, 0.973832136657044, 0.978059833099735, 
1, 0.246299519388515, 0.945461616197224, 0.980265015416377, 0.988163901155937, 
0.942210041798293, -0.304138745456209, 0.260477742974566, 0.251853284084679, 
0.241345600979638, 0.246299519388515, 1, 0.175351977633108, 0.254175573791427, 
0.241722979690123, 0.200038950214348, -0.622365632769871, 0.928971036770817, 
0.941236887557877, 0.934105190260024, 0.945461616197224, 0.175351977633108, 
1, 0.930342825056357, 0.94185467129245, 0.963675695468988, -0.238684953080287, 
0.990859133037916, 0.970317460375686, 0.991280098453041, 0.980265015416377, 
0.254175573791427, 0.930342825056357, 1, 0.988245057126345, 0.924562105692743, 
-0.305337729938945, 0.98615828324931, 0.979203650433608, 0.987744430218514, 
0.988163901155937, 0.241722979690123, 0.94185467129245, 0.988245057126345, 
1, 0.936651970737347, -0.294420287372996, 0.923912532530861, 
0.931475199702801, 0.923127024136395, 0.942210041798293, 0.200038950214348, 
0.963675695468988, 0.924562105692743, 0.936651970737347, 1, -0.270230372039959, 
-0.328655580485871, -0.262254189238524, -0.287964556946545, -0.304138745456209, 
-0.622365632769871, -0.238684953080287, -0.305337729938945, -0.294420287372996, 
-0.270230372039959, 1), .Dim = c(10L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("jpm", "gs", "ms", "bofa", "schwab", "brk", "wf", "citi", 
    "amex", "spgl"), c("jpm", "gs", "ms", "bofa", "schwab", "brk", 
    "wf", "citi", "amex", "spgl")))

g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjm, weighted=T, mode="undirected", diag=F)
plot(g, layout=layout_nicely)
```

Comment: Are you sure what you have there is an adjacency matrix? For example, they typically consist of 1's and 0's, with 0's on the diagonal. What you have looks more like correlation coefficients.

Comment: Yeah you are correct, it's not the adjacency matrix, it's the correlations which would count as the weights. I will edit that. @DavidClarke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjm, weighted = "wt", mode = "undirected", diag = F)
plot(g, edge.label = round(E(g)$wt, 2))
```

where the weights as a edge attribute is named as `wt` in `graph_from_adjacency_matrix`. Then, when you plot `g`, you can specify that you want to print `wt` as the edge labels by `edge.label = round(E(g)$wt, 2)`.

[image]